# Is it possible to translate binary to light signals?

Tags: led

I have a doubt.
Could I translate a binary code to light signals?

For example:

01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00001010

Could I use an LED to emit that binary code through light signals?.

Comment: You mean kinda like a fiber-optic undersea cable .... ? Or even a TOSLINK optical audio ... ? Or fiber-optic ethernet ... ?

Comment: Get an LED flashlight and a friend. To send a one point the light at him or her for 1 second. To send a zero point it away. If your friend writes down what they see you will have successfully sent that binary as light.

Comment: or have a friend stand in a dark room. Turn the light switch on and off and have him write down the sequence.

Comment: @pat I see. That's the idea. ON is 1 and 0 is OFF but what if there is something like: 100001? Im starting to think its not possible. I received a message trough light from an intelligent being and I have the task to decode it, but now im starting to think that It could be a different code, I'm assuming its not binary.

Comment: You could encode your binary data in different ways - perhaps a short flash for a Zero and a long flash for a One. Or use the standard UART format - a series of bits of fixed duration following a start bit - three Zeros in a row would be light off for three bit times.

Comment: @JohnHarris You are prodding. You know darned well it can be done. It's what [optical backplanes](https://grouper.ieee.org/groups/802/802_tutorials/2014-03/20140317IEEE802TutorialOBackplaneB.pdf) do, for example. If you want to see something kind of silly but 'functional' then watch [a 4 minute youtube showing transmitted audio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TuijpcqUWoQ). But for digital data without too much complexity, you can try [FSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying) with an MCU and use the [Görtzel DFT algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm).

Comment: Or navy signal lights

Comment: Short and long can be used - like morse code.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you guys. I think @PeterBennett's answer is what I need in this particular case, now I just need to analyze the duration of every bit.

Comment: @jonk Thats very cool, I will definitely learn about it all, it sounds amazing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JohnHarris There are so many ways. Just open up your imagination. But FSK is pretty easy to achieve and it works well. All you do is switch between two different modulation frequencies. You can do that either synchronously (switching at a particular phase) or asynchronously (not caring about bothering with the phase.) There are some trade-offs between the two. But the basic idea, ignoring that detail, is pretty easy to acquire.

Comment: @JohnHarris if you asked about the problem that you are trying to solve, instead of an "is it possible?" question, then you may have not gathered any downvotes ... what is the signal that you are trying to decode?

Answer (score 4):

> Could I use an LED to emit that binary code through light signals?.

Of course, but if you want some device to receive it and decode it on the other side, it gets a bit more involved.

If there is no outside interfering light source, for example in optical fiber, then you could simply drive a LED on/off with the bits, use a photodiode or phototransistor at the other end, and recover the bits. So it's a bit like a wire, and you get the same problems: if there is a long string of contiguous identical bits, the receiver might get lost because there is no "marker" to designate where each bit starts and stops. You would need some form of encoding, like oldskool serial, Manchester coding, 8b10b encoding, etc, to make sure the receiver knows where the bits are.

If there is outside interfering light, then modulation is usually the solution. For example in TV remove control, it's not just on/off according to the bits, rather when it wants to transmit a "1" the LED blinks at some high frequency like 36kHz, and when it wants to transmit a "0" it stays off. Two different frequencies for 1 and 0 would also work. The idea is that with outside light sources adding their own light to the signal, it is much easier to detect a modulation in the intensity of the light than just comparing the received value to a threshold.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to translate binary to light signals?

### IR is light, isn't it?

Remote controls using IR data have existed for a long time, yet long after semaphore used flash codes between ships.

Now you can send data from LEDs in the ceiling without noticing any flicker, if you wanted to, but due to diode capacitance, not nearly as fast as Bluetooth wireless.

Have you seen any other examples?
hmmm like Laser Networking between buildings.

### Protocol

Because IR remotes conserve power , they send a burst preamble to allow the Sharp/Vishay IR decoder AGC circuits to charge up. They use one of many carrier frequencies in a band to improve performance rejection of fluorescent and other flickering lights from 20 to 60 kHz, then modulate the amplitude of data with a certain pattern.  Then data patterns are repeated until the button is released.

For an ACDC powered unit using a UART that isn't necessary if you use full brightness as the idle +V in RS232 or "0V" in TTL. Then the start bit could be a 90% drop in level rather than 100% with some ambient noise raising the 0% IR level, you would use 10% peak for the  other bit.  If you wanted synchronous data then to avoid long periods of data at the 10% level, and challenges with clock recovery, you could use biphase, but added thru put and simple complexity may be beyond your needs.

There are a few standards of optical communication for near field 1 m and far field using IR Tx, Rx with 1m high speed capability, called IRDA and IRDA2, which is also decades old technology well-documented on the web.

that's for a serious answer for a naive question. Have fun with it.

Answer (score 2):

Any kind of thing that has at least 2 discernible states can be used to represent binary, be it electrical, optical, or some other means.

The question then becomes, how far, how fast, and how much cost? Let’s look at some optical options:

- if you have a flashlight you could send some kind of code using the switch - short pulse for ‘0’ and long pulse for ‘1’, say. Or learn Morse code (although Morse doesn’t know upper or lower case - bit of an issue for your example string.) This would be the ‘original gangster’ way.
- Infrared remotes are very cheap, work up to about 10m, and send data at about 2400 baud.
- IrDA is a suite of protocols that work up to 4Mbit in close proximity; more like 200kbit for normal in-room distances.
- Laser links can work at thousands of yards and support Gbit speeds.
- Fiber optic cables can carry multi-Gbit signals that cross oceans.

If you’re interested in remote control stuff there are open-source libraries like *lirc* that support it. IrDA was popular in the PDA era, but has largely been supplanted by Bluetooth and other wireless protocols.

There is recent work being done to piggyback on infrastructure LED lighting to send data. Potentially it could offer much higher throughput than wireless without some of the interference issues that come with Wi-Fi and other RF protocols. Feels a bit Videodrome-ish to me…